# Kendo UI Multiselect Tag mode - filter based on typed value not passing the typed text to server

Tags: kendo-ui, tags, multi-select

This is the code which I am using to bind Multiselect to listbox in javascript. I am not where I am missing, I am not receiving the typed text in ajax call to get values. The method gets called in the controller side and the string parameter which I have returns null.

Implemented based on URL: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/addnewitem

```
 $("#Tags").kendoMultiSelect({
                placeholder: "Select your tags",
                dataTextField: "Name",
                dataValueField: "Id",
                autoBind: false,
                maxSelectedItems: 5,
                minLength: 3,
                delay: 2000,
                //filter: "startswith",
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "/Support/Ticket/GetTags",
                            dataType: "json"
                        }
                    },
                    serverFiltering:true
                }
            });
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult GetTags(string text)
{
    List<Tag> tags = _tagRepository.GetAll(text).ToList();
    return Json(tags);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned here https://www.telerik.com/forums/server-filtering-not-working-as-expected#KXcqO6xHoE6NxGuL0T2ZoQ, I think you need to add return data option

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
           $("#products").kendoMultiSelect({
               placeholder: "Select products...",
               dataTextField: "ProductName",
               dataValueField: "ProductID",
               dataSource: {
                   type: "odata",
                   serverFiltering: true,
                   transport: {
                       read: {
                           url: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Products",
                           data: function () {                               
                               return {
                                   text: $("#products").data('kendoMultiSelect').input.val()
                               };
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           });
       });
```

Comment: Hi HaBo, I tried your solution and still I receive an error message in Jquery, Error: jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'input' of undefined